# Grouping formula to account for two fields

Tags: crystal-reports

Working with vehicle asset management and I am selecting data based on two statements:

```
({EQ_MAIN.PROCST_PROC_STATUS} in ["A", "AS", "AT"] and
{EQ_MAIN.DEPT_DEPT_CODE} like "P*" and
{EQ_MAIN.ASSET_TYPE} <> "COMPONENT") 
or
({EQ_MAIN.PROCST_PROC_STATUS} in ["TA"] and
{EQ_MAIN.DEPT_TEMP_LOANED_TO} like "P*" and
{EQ_MAIN.ASSET_TYPE} <> "COMPONENT")
```

Basically, if the Equipment is in status A, AS, or AT and belongs to the departments that start with P, I want it to show on the report. However, the second part of the selection statement accounts for equipment that is temporarily loaned to another department (status TA). The selection statements seem to be working fine.

I have this data grouped by {EQ_MAIN.DEPT_DEPT_CODE}. But I want it to to include any temporarily loaned out equipment under the department group, if the equipment is on temp loan to said department. For example, Car A belongs to department K1234, but is on loan to department P5678. I want Car A to show up under the group for P5678 along with all the other vehicles that belong to P5678. Essentially, whether a piece of eq belongs to a specific department or is simply on loan to said specific department, I want to see them under the same group in Crystal. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that a grouping formula is the solution for this scenario.  The challenge is based in the recordset.  Since there is only one `LOANED_TO` record per `DEPT_CODE`, you can go about this a couple of ways.

1. If this is an option, modify your query or view so that you generate all `LOANED_TO` records for each `DEPT_CODE`.  This could be achieved by placing a subquery in your FROM clause if using SQL.  Then, join your parent table `EQ_MAIN` to the subquery on a non-unique, general key.  Since there is no one-to-one relationship in this scenario, you should get all `LOANED_TO` records for each `DEPT_CODE`.  This will, however, bloat your recordset and mar performance.
   Then, group the report first on `{DEPT_CODE}` and second on `{LOANED_TO}`.  Use a suppression formula on the second group to hide any `{LOANED_TO}` Departments that do not match the parent group `{DEPT_CODE}`.
2. The more "traditional" Crystal approach is to group on `{DEPT_CODE}`.  Then, add a sub report to a group section.  Using the same datasource, move the second chunk of selection criteria (following the OR clause) to the sub report record selection.  This will return all `{LOANED_TO}` records.  Add a sub report link between the group `{DEPT_CODE}` and the sub report `{LOANED_TO}` dept.  This will filter results to just those `{LOANED_TO}` records related to the main group.